# Cant access JSON object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am having trouble accessing a JSON object's property. I am using SheetJS to parse an excel file and store it as an array of JSON objects. This part works fine (the getData() function). I want to parse this array and set a new property if the "RunName" property starts with a "NK". I have attempted to implement a 'setPriority()' function but the code cannot find the RunName property, giving me the 'unresolved variable name' error. I have added my code and an example of the structure of the array below. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks:)

```
var url = "TestData.xlsx";
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", url, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

function getData() {

    oReq.onload = function (e) {
        var arraybuffer = oReq.response;

        /* convert data to binary string */
        var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
        var arr = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
        var bstr = arr.join("");


        /* Call XLSX */
        var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type: "binary"});

        /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
        var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
        var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];

        var array = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {raw: true});


        console.log(array);


        setPriority(array);


    };

    oReq.send();

}


function setPriority(array) {


    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        switch (array[i].RunName) {

            case (/NK/):
                array[i].Priority = 2;


        }


    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
switch (array[i].RunName.indexOf('NK')) {

    case (0):
        array[i].Priority = 2;
}
```

`switch` statements evaluate the expression inside the switch's brackets, and then try to match the evaluated expression against the case expressions using **strict comparison**, so using `===`. For example, if we have the following code:

```
var i = 5;
switch (i) {
  case ("5"):
    console.log("Five as string");
    break;
  case (5):
    console.log("Five");
    break;
}
```

First, `i` is evaluated, resulting in the value `5`. Then the case expressions are evaluated case by case, first testing `5 === "5"`, which is false. Then the next one, `5 === 5`, which is true, so the code inside the case block is executed.

I'm unsure about regexes and why you got the error you did, but in any case, `"NK" === /NK/` is false, so there's no way it will match. The solution is just to use a switch expression that evaluates into an easily comparable value, and create the case expressions accordingly - so in the switch expression, we check the index of the first occurrence of `"NK"`, and if it occurs at index 0 - the first index of the string - we execute the code inside the case block.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you! Could you please explain where I went wrong, and the difference between what I did and your solution? Thanks again!

Comment: @DylanBaxter Added some explanation - my knowledge on JS regexes and switches is limited, but hopefully it clears at least something up

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, really helps. Because I need to check the whole array and set a different priority for each group (e.g. priority 1 for NK, priority 2 for NB etc), I will need to use regular expressions to check for the first to characters. Otherwise, a series of if statements?

Comment: I have resolved this issue. I am using:

'switch (array[i].RunName.substring(0,2) {

    case ('NK'):
        array[i].Priority = 1;
break;

case ('NB'):
array[i].Priority = 2
break;
}'